# How to aplay append in runOnUiThread with Kotlin to Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this piece of code in Kotlin for Android and I need to apply append to the `messageReceived` variable. How can I do it?

```
private lateinit var messageReceived: TextView

this.messageReceived = findViewById(R.id.messageRreceived)

private fun updateReceivedMessage(newPayload: String) {
    runOnUiThread { messageReceived.text = newPayload }
}
```

Comment: Hi @w1ll, Could you share what you exactly want. I couldn't understand your problem correctly. Detailed description of what's ur expected outcome along with what you have done till now will help much better

Comment: `messageReceived` is a view, what is `appned`? What do you want to `appned`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the text first and then set the new text

```
private fun updateReceivedMessage(newPayload: String) {
    runOnUiThread {
        val previousText = messageReceived.text.toString()
        messageReceived.text = "$previousText $newPayload"
    }
}
```

You could make it more readable with a line break maybe

```
messageReceived.text = "$previousText\n$newPayload"
```

Comment: It's also a good approach but it creates a new variable un-necessarily. as you have a method for updating that might get called multiple times and creating a variable everytime is not a good practice.
You can go for global variable declaration but you can do it wihtout any extra vaiable. see my answer.

Comment: Modern compilers ignore extra variables for optimization, at this point is a given fact, anyway made a POC and check my information is correct https://www.codepile.net/pile/V4eLzAX8 double shift on Intellij Idea, show byte code, decompile and there is no creation of new variables. That optimization you are suggesting is automatic, and therefore code redability should be prioritize.

Comment: Thanks for extra info i didnt know this.

Answer (score 0):

If you like want to append text message then instead of assiging "newPayload" directly, go with

```
messageReceived.text = messageReceived.text.toString() + newPayload
or 
messageReceived.text = messageReceived.text.toString().plus(newPayload)
```